# Is there a way to connect a process to X window manager?

Tags: linux, windows, xlib

I am running this process on Linux.   This is a server process that does not have direct connection to X Server.  The process needs to run an X utility tool ( xinput command).   The xinput command is being fork off and exec from the server process.  The problem that I have is when the xinput command is executed, it received "Unable to connect to X server".  This is understandable because command was not executed from the desktop environment.  The server is running on a workstation that has a desktop.  It just that the server process was not started from the desktop.  Is there a way for server process to connect X server so that xinput can be executed ?    Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes! Well, maybe. In X, the X client programs ‘know’ how to connect via environment variables or the special command-line options. See: https://gerardnico.com/ssh/x11/display , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization - depending on exact configuration it may need to be a network connection. Anyway, just tell the client program how to “phone home” and grant connectivity and authorization. Tunnels can also be very useful.

Comment: And still closing as OT.. see the general / *ix SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.   In case someone else has similar question.   Here is my solution.
Create 2 files -- A shell file and another file that you are accessing from X utility command.  I use bash shell but you can use some other shell.  The yourCommand is the script where you want to access X stuff.  The DISPLAY must be set before running ssh.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=0.0
ssh -X workstation yourCommand
```